# Rmarkdown knitting to markdown changes hashed headers

Tags: hash, header, r-markdown, markdown

I am trying to knit from Rmarkdown to markdown.

When knitting

```
---
output: md_document
---

# Header 1

## Header 2
```

I get

```
Header 1
========

Header 2
--------
```

but I want the Headers to remain hashed which is valid markdown. How can I accomplish this from within the Rmd?

It works with

```
---
output: 
  html_document:
      keep_md: true
---
```

but since I am conditionally compiling different content in the actual rmarkdown to html and md I cannot use this option.

Answer (score 0):

When you run

```
---
output: 
  html_document:
      keep_md: true
---

# Header 1

## Header 2
```

In the present working directory of this .Rmd file, Rstudio/Rmarkdown should render a .md file that is the actual Markdown file, while also rendering an HTML file. Which, when opens, shows the code just like the .RMD file has

[image]
[image]

[This link](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/markdown-document.html) May also give some more info regarding Rmarkdon YAML options for more markdown control.